# MPI on single process

Tags: mpi

I'm new on cluster tecnology and i'm testing a MPICH2 cluster solution for my company.

We have a c program that actually act in this way:

- There is one master process that connect to database ad prepare the data
- The master process create some child processes with different command line argument (the slave processes are created with fork() command)

Is possible to run these process on MPICH2 cluster without modification?
Otherwise, what modification are needed for run this program on cluster?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get confused between parallel processes on a single machine and distributed processes (via MPI) because they're not the same thing. There was another question asked today that had the same problem so I'll refer you to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26428033/491687.

Calling `fork()` will only create more processes on the same machine as the master process. If you are only going to be using shared memory and a few processes, that's fine. However, if you need to process lots of data using lots of processes (number of processes > number of cores, roughly), then MPI can be helpful because it allows you connect multiple machines together and pass data around between them.

So the short answer is: No, you can't use MPI without modification. There's a huge amount of modification necessary to convert a fork/join program to an MPI program. That's by design. They don't try to solve the same problem.